# How to write strings in Math Equations in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex

I want to write the next equation (only the first part)

[image]

in a Jupyter notebook.

When I tried with this code

```
\begin{gather*}
Sensitivity = \frac{number true positives}{number of true positivities + number of false negatives}  
\end{gather*}
```

I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can embed text in LaTeX:

```latex
\text{Some text with spaces}
```

So in your case, it could look like this:

```latex
\begin{gather*}
Sensitivity = \frac{\text{number true positives}}{\text{number of true positivities} + \text{number of false negatives}}  
\end{gather*}
```